# Преобразование даты в другой формат через JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вот такая дата Thu Mar 31 2022 15:06:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)
Мне необходимо её преобразовать в формат, который поддерживает datetime-local

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/   ---посмотри.

Comment: Что за datetime-local ?

Comment: <input type= "datetime-local">

Comment: А как подключить эту библиотеку? Он её не находит

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, что нет необходимости подключать какие-либо библиотеки, и стоит попробовать стандартные методы. Следует учитывать, что это решение конкретно данного вопроса:

> ... преобразовать в формат, который поддерживает datetime-local

- Без учёта часового пояса:

```js
let input = 'Thu Mar 31 2022 15:06:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)';
let output = new Date(Date.parse(input)).toISOString().slice(0, -1);

document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]').value = output;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
```

- С учётом часового пояса переданного в строке:

```js
let input = 'Thu Mar 31 2022 15:06:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)';
let originalOffset = parseInt(input.slice(28, 29) + (input.slice(29, 31) * 60 + +input.slice(31, 33))) * 60000;
let output = new Date(Date.parse(input) + originalOffset).toISOString().slice(0, -1);

document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]').value = output;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
```